# How to get Recently Viewed Product Widget without using widget or static block. Magento 2.3.1

Tags: products, magento2.3.1, recently-viewed

I want to get the Recently Viewed Products without using Widget or static Block I tried this

```
namespace PME\Hideprice\Block;

class getTestingData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        parent::__construct( $context, $data );
    }

    public function testing(){
        return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->getData();
        //return "Asad Khan";
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

but both of these does not return me anything

but these classes does not return me anything. How to get all the recently viewed product?

Comment: please try injecting this block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed instead

Comment: Sir I tried that one also didn't return me anything

Comment: do you see recently viewed products in your widget?

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to get the recently viewed data by widget. I want to get it by functions

Comment: please verify that there are actually recently viewed products! maybe that's the issue. you can't assume that you click on a product and it will show up in your collection.

Comment: Yes Sir! I verified this n tried as well working perfectly but if I'm getting this in code then it returns nothing.. like I mention the above code.

Comment: Sir I updated my answer where I mention the 2nd try as well that I tried to get Recently Viewed Products. but both of these classes does not return me anything

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
namespace PME\Hideprice\Block;

class getTestingData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }  
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function testing()
    {
        $collection = $this->_recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
             $info = $data->getData();
             print_r($info);      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Sir but this isn't working returning null array like *array()*

Comment: $data->getData() returning null array ??

Comment: Yes Sir it gives me null array also when I tried `return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->getData();` or `return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->load()->getData();` n these r also sending me null array